# Blackberry WebWorks SMS Listener Exception

Tags: javascript, blackberry, sms, listener, blackberry-webworks

Specs:
WebWorks 2.2, Curve 9330 OS 6 Simulator and Device

We'll, I've tried just about everything and I can't figure this out. My application has a main page (index.html) and a background page (listener.html), as specified here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
   xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" 
   version="1.0.0.0" rim:header="SimpleSMS">
   <name>SimpleSMS</name>
   <description>Simple SMS</description>
   <content src="index.html">
       <rim:background src="listener.html" runOnStartup="true" />
   </content>
   <rim:navigation mode="focus" />
   <access subdomains="false" uri="http://jsconsole.com"/>
   <feature id="blackberry.message.sms" />
   <feature id="blackberry.app" />
   <feature id="blackberry.io.dir" />
   <feature id="blackberry.io.file" />
   <feature id="blackberry.utils" />
</widget>
```

The listener.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="message_db2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initializeListener();">
    </body>
</html>
```

The initializeListener() function is as follows:

```
function initializeListener() {
    blackberry.message.sms.isListeningForMessage = true;
    blackberry.message.sms.addReceiveListener(messageListener);
}
```

The issue:
When I install my app, and the listener starts running, my app can receive text messages without problems. As soon as I open the main application, the problems begin. If I just minimize the app to the background using the back or end button, the next sms received causes an exception. If I close the app through the menu, there's no exception, but the listener ceases to function. I have commented all code in messageListener and index.html does absolutely nothing but display some html. There is almost no documentation regarding having a background page. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, were you able to listen and read an incoming SMS on a blackberry using WebWorks 2.2? If yes, would you like to explain shortly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that webworks is going to these different pages and discarding everything that's in the previous page? *(Like what happens to a form you fill out when you go to a new page in your browser)*

Maybe you need to make use of [Application Events](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.app.event.html) to check when the app goes to the Foreground or Background; Maybe double check isListeningForMessage?

I'm thinking of something like

```
function onFG()
{
  if (!blackberry.message.sms.isListeningForMessage)
  {
    blackberry.message.sms.isListeningForMessage = true;
    blackberry.message.sms.addReceiveListener(messageListener);
  }
}

blackberry.app.event.onForeground(onFG);
```

You can also make use of [isForeground](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.app.html#.isForeground) boolean if you need to have your code distinguish where it is running.